# Mixed Mode on Windows CE / Compact Framework

Tags: windows-ce, mixed-mode

is there a way to create a mixed mode application/dll for Windows CE (version 6.0), with  installed Compact Framework (version >2.0)? 
The Source Code was written in C++. I only succeded in building pure .NET applications based on C#. When using Visual Studio (2005) and adding /CLR to the command line I receive the warning 
"cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/CLR'"

Thanks for every hint in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't.  The major problem is that the compiler for the compact framework supports only C# and VB.NET.  Compiling any other language can result in IL that contains [opcodes that the Compact Framework doesn't support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bluecollar/archive/2006/09/27/773065.aspx).

There is also [a bug in the CF](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/319532/strong-name-validation-fails-on-compact-framework-when-pe-section-sizeofrawdata-less-than-virtualsize) regarding strong name validation that prevents it from working.

If you'd like to read about someone else's efforts at getting mixed mode working, specifically for SQLite, take a look [at this thread](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/1187.aspx).